# Drupal pagecall first hook

Tags: path, drupal-7, hook

When a page is called, I want to check the call on depending on the path, I want to redirect the user to the frontpage, with some parameters. These parameters I will use in a block to show extra information to the visitor.

What hook should I use, so that drupal has to do the least unnecessary work ?

Answer (score 0):

1) The [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) function is the appropriate hook here.

2) An alternative option is to use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Event: Drupal is initializing (using hook_init)
Condition: Execute custom php code (check path argument)
Actions: Page redirect, Other rules actions (eg a Message)

I would suggest to **show a Drupal Message** to the user instead of a block. Except if user is logged in and parameters shown in block do exist in the database so you can use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to create that block.

Here is an export of a rule that redirects if the taxonomy term page display belongs to Vocabulary '4'. Import it to your rules to see the results.

```
{ "rules_taxonomy_redirect_business" : {
    "LABEL" : "Taxonomy redirect - Business",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "redirect", "taxonomy" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "init" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "$check1 = (arg(0)==\u0027taxonomy\u0027)\u0026\u0026(arg(1)==\u0027term\u0027);\r\n$check2 = (arg(3)!=\u0027edit\u0027);\r\n\r\nif (arg(2)) {\r\n$tid = arg(2);\r\n$vid = db_query(\u0027SELECT vid FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE tid = :tid\u0027, array(\u0027:tid\u0027 =\u003E $tid))-\u003EfetchField();\r\n$check3 = ($vid == \u00274\u0027);\r\n}\r\n\r\nreturn ($check1)\u0026\u0026($check2)\u0026\u0026($check3);" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "\u003C?php\r\n$tid = arg(2);\r\nreturn \u0027business?cat%5B%5D=\u0027 . $tid;\r\n?\u003E" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Rules could be used. But it is not a question of how to implement it, but hooking into drupal as early as possible so that the least amount of work needs to be done by drupal. At the moment I use a hook_init, but that means a lot of unnecessary code has been executed by drupal allready.